# Filling a region in the complex plane in Matlab

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, matlab, math-software, implicit-function

So I have plotted the the function defined implicitly by `fimplicit` in Matlab. I want to fill the region inside. How to do that?

```
f1=@(x,y) (1+x+x.^2-y.^2).^2+(y+2.*x.*y).^2-1;

fimplicit(f1)
hold on
axis([-1.5 0.5 -1.5 1.5])
xlabel('Re(h\lambda)')
ylabel('Im(h\lambda)')
hold off
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Matlab program which does the job:

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on
> axis([-1.5 0.5 -1.5 1.5])
> e=ezplot('(1+x+x^2-y^2).^2+(y+2*x*y)^2-1');
> t=get(e,'ContourMatrix')
> fill(t(1,2:end),t(2,2:end),'r')
> ```

Please note:

- that I have used easyplot ("ezplot") instead of your (perfectly good) definition of function, because I am using an old release...
- The presence of function "fill" (instead of "plot"). Take care: the first element contains size information in its first entry ; this is why we use the array of coordinates $t$ from $2$ to "end".